# crt.Dialog.FileOpenDialog([title, [buttonLabel, [defaultFilename, [filter ]]]])

Tags: vbscript, secure-crt

When I am trying to browse for a file using  crt.Dialog.FileOpenDialog(attributes as required),the browsing window is not appearing on the top rather its appearing behind some other windows.

I tried using focus but didn't get the desired output.

```
CommDecodeFileNameSelected = crt.Dialog.FileOpenDialog("Select csv Filename to upload", "Upload", "", "All Files (*.txt)|*.log||")                
CommDecode_g_objIE.Document.All("filename").value = CommDecodeFileNameSelected
```

I am expecting the browsing window to appear on top.

Answer (score 0):

Before the above two lines add

```
CommDecode_g_objIE.Document.All("ButtonHandler").Value = "Nothing Clicked Yet"
CommDecode_g_objIE.Visible = False
CommDecodeFileNameSelected = crt.Dialog.FileOpenDialog("Select csv Filename to upload", "Upload", "", "All Files (*.txt)|*.log||")                
CommDecode_g_objIE.Document.All("filename").value = CommDecodeFileNameSelected
```